# RestKit postponing and concurrent requests

Tags: restkit

In the old RestKit 0.10 there was the guarantee, that all request and responses travel thru `RKRequestQueue` with the benefit of "managed request memory", "managed network load" (limit concurrent requests to 5), "managed request life cycle", "managed network availability" (including postponing request until the network is reachable).

With RestKit >= 0.20.0 the `RKRequestQueue` is not available any more.

Are those features provided by the old `RKRequestQueue` still valid for 0.20.0 and up? Is there a limit for concurrent requests? Is there a postponing feature until the network is reachable and if so who provides this?

Answer (score 1):

This would now be managed by the `AFHTTPClient` that you can get from the `RKObjectManager` that you're using. You can get the `operationQueue` from the client to configure concurrency. You can also use `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` to be notified of network status changes and react to them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint to `operationQueue`. But I was not looking for a way to configure this by myself. One can argue that RestKit is open source and thus you can do anything. I was wondering if the concept of RestKit to manage concurrent requests and postponing is still valid for the 0.20 version. Basically does RestKit configure and manage those features or do we have to do it by ourself starting from 0.20

Comment: RestKits purpose is the mapping and serialisation. The comms is handled by AFNetworking so you need to use the facilities that it provides.